# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Cookies empty on subdomain

Tags: cookies, subdomain

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET Core 1.0 website but I've got a problem.
The context is that my website is using a subdomain like sub.domain.com
I set cookies on my application and it's working great.

When I go to the domain.com application, some cookies are set too.

Then, when I come back to sub.domain.com, the first cookies are still set and sent to the application but if I debug the application I see that the request context doesn't contain any cookie, nor the one I sent, nor any other one.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Uhm.. do you expect the cookies from domain.tld to be submitted to sub.domain.tld?

Comment: This should do it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain